# Using custom Font, font does not change in React native

Tags: react-native, fonts

What could be the reason for this?

I have downloaded the Poppins fonts and followed some tutorial in order to see if i can use Poppins fonts in my React native project. the Project is still very much stunned and nothing changes (Although its a test project, have not embarked on the real thing yet.)

so i downloaded the font (As said earlier), and created a file / folder called Assets and have the tff file saved inside the folder respectively which looks thus :

[image: sed.png]

Then i created a file react.native.config.js which looks like this

[image: sdf.png]

Then React native does not allow to link no more, hence i did npx react-native-assets

The problem i have now, is the font does not even change despite everything. Is there something i do not appear to be doing correctly?

Comment: Android or iOS or both?

Comment: both, i need for both.